# Moving a control at the bottom left of the screen at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a Windows Forms application with C# and the Form size is 1200x800. There's a Picture Box called RivalCube which moves at runtime at the bottom left using the command `RivalCube.Location = new Point(0, 677);`. It works fine, but if you make the Application full screen and you start it it places the Picture Box somewhere in the middle of the screen because being Maximized makes it bigger so 0,677 is no longer the bottom left of the screen. So how do I make sure it stays at the bottom even if the application resizes?
I'v tried anchoring it but it still does not work.

Thanks alot !

Comment: Set it's anchor to bottom and right.

Comment: Anchoring did not work.

Comment: The job of `Anchor` property is what you are looking for. Is your PictureBox hosted in another control like panel?

Comment: Oh yes it is, I changed it and now it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the resize event of the form add your code for the picture box's movement

Like this:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RivalCube.Location = new Point(0, 677);
    }
```